# Transition between scenes and unwanted text is staying visible.

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs6

> I would like to ask you about my problem. 
>   I have two different scenes and when i change from second scene to first scene, text from second scene is still staying visible and does not disappear, how it should. It is maybe hard to discribe, but i really dont know what to do with this...

Comment: I have also picture there and i have found out, the picture is probably too big and when i remove him, it is okay, so i will try to resize him and if this will not help, i dont know...

Comment: what's the problem? if you don't need it in the scene, just delete it from the scene.